# TypeScript React Functional Component - is missing the following properties from type 'Element': type, props, key error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom

I have the following definitions:

**IRoute:**

```
export interface IRoute{
    key: string, 
    path: string,
    exact: boolean,
    component: JSX.Element,
    private?: boolean
}
```

**IRoutesConfig:**

```
import { IRoute } from "./IRoute";

export default interface IRoutesConfig {
    [key : string] : [IRoute]
}
```

and my **Routes Configration**, that I will then pass on to a class for further enhancements

```
import Login from "../container/Auth/Login/Login";
import IRoutesConfig from "./IRoutesConfig";

const Routes : IRoutesConfig = {
    "Auth": [
        {
            key: "login-page",
            exact: true, 
            component: Login,
            path: "/auth/login"
        }
    ]
}

export default Routes;
```

I am testing with a **Login functional component**:

```
import React, { FC, ReactElement } from 'react';

type LoginProps = {

}

const Login : FC<LoginProps> = (props) : ReactElement => {
  return (
    <>
    
    </>
  );
}

export default Login;
```

This is a new project setup and there isn't anything defined yet for the Login Props. So it is currently left empty and will be extended later on, same goes for the content, as we are currently setting up the routes architecture.

VSCode is giving me the following hint over "***component***" in `Routes:IRoutesConfig`:

[image: vscode error]

Of course I am not declaring type, props and key.

At the end the routes config will be given to a RouteManager, that will dynamically create `Routes` for the `Switch` of `React-Router-Dom', plus some other stuff, depending on where I access it.

It will create a map of routes such as:

```
<Route key="login-page" path="/auth/login" component={Login} />
```

Which is then used in a react container component:

```
...

let authRoutes = RoutesManager.getAllRoutes("Auth");

return (
    <Switch>
      {authRoutes}
      <Redirect key="account-redirect" to="/account" />
    </Switch>
  );
```

**Question:**
From my understanding, the r`eact-router-dom route` expects in it's arg `component` a `JSX.element`, however the return type of my Login functional component is a ReactElement. JSX.element is a generic ReactElement in this context, as far as I understood it. The Login FC will have children.

How can I solve the issue of passing the Login FC to the config correctly, to be later used by the route component of react-router-dom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understood the error is from `component: JSX.Element`. And you're trying to create protected routes by adding a `private` property to `Route`. You can change your `IRoute` interface to extend the `react-router` defined types so you won't face this issue enay more.

**First**: Add this import statement.

```
import { RouteProps } from "react-router-dom";
```

**Second**: change your `IRoute` inteface to this:

```
export interface IRoute extends RouteProps{
    private?: boolean
}
```

In this way, You simply telling that my `IRoute` has all of the simple `Route` properties plus `private`.

Comment: Thank you, that made it much easier. I think my component declaration was way to simple, as RouteProps actually defines component as "(property) RouteProps.component?: React.ComponentClass<RouteComponentProps<any, StaticContext, unknown>, any> | React.FunctionComponent<RouteComponentProps<any, StaticContext, unknown>> | React.ComponentClass<...> | React.FunctionComponent<...> | undefined".

Comment: @Richard Yeah in the first look your declaration was simple. But every types of components have its own pros and cons and might force you to have some properties you won't need. `RouteProps` accepts every valid component types so you won't struggle when you want to use a component without props for example.